# Connecting microsoft Exchange server with java

Tags: java, active-directory, jakarta-mail

I have a problem in connecting microsoft exchange server active directory with java using Java Mail. it is throwing an exception

> javax.mail.MessagingException: No login methods supported!;

or sometimes

> com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: 220

i just want a simple idea to how to actually connect with an exchange server active dirrectory.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that you did not enable SNMP support on your exchange server. Check it. Exchange server supports various protocols but its default protocol is proprietary, while Java mail API works with SNMP.

Comment: Why is it related to SNMP?  Do you mean SMTP?

Comment: Domain joined clients connect to Exchange via MAPI by default, which is available to other email clients.  If it's a non-domain joined client, the only other piece to configure is RPC proxy (RPC over HTTP/S); SMTP never comes into play (assuming messages at least getting to the server normally).  If you cannot get MAPI to work, POP and IMAP are still viable options.